# Can I Uncheck selected checkbox on a Button click in Datagrid Material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I created a grid in Datagrid Material-UI where I am using a checkbox. After clicking on the checkbox, I want to uncheck by clicking the reset button.

Example:

[image]

DataGrid Code I am using:

> ```
>  <DataGrid
>                         rows={props.rows}
>                         columns={props.columns}
>                         onSelectionChange={(newSelection) => {
>                             handleSelected(newSelection);
>                         }}
>                         disableSelectionOnClick
>                         checkboxSelection
>                         disableColumnMenu
>                         pageSize={10}
>                     />
> ```

**Note: props contain data there are rows and columns. I don't want to do a page reload because the page has other data that should not be reset**

Comment: Where do you track the state of what rows are checked?  Your button click handler would update that state.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the handleSelected to [] on the onClick property of Reset button, something like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => handleSelected([])} >Reset</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a checkbox of tasks to be added to the server.

I used this to handle which tasks are checked.

```
[checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState([]);
```

I passed this as prop to the checkbox component

```
<Checkbox
  onChange={handleChange}
  checked={checkedList.includes(newTask.node)}
/>
```

```
export function Checkbox() {
  const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { checked, value } = e.target;
    const tempCheckedList = [...checkedList];

    if (checked) {
      tempCheckedList.push(value);
      setCheckedList(tempCheckedList);
    } else {
      const updatedList = tempCheckedList.filter(
        (taskNode) => taskNode != value
      );
      setCheckedList(updatedList);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCheckedList([]);
  };

  return (
    <FormGroup
      row
    >
      {newTasks.map((newTask) => {
        return (
          <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox
                onChange={handleChange}
                checked={checkedList.includes(newTask.node)}
              />
            }
            value={newTask.node}
            label={newTask.node}
            key={newTask.node}
          />
        );
      })}
      <Button
        onClick={handleSubmit}
        variant='contained'
        endIcon={<KeyboardArrowRight />}
        disabled={!checkedList.length}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```